# WindowInsetsControllerCompat does not hide navigation bars

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

I have an app with app bar and bottom navigation bars visible by default.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

At some point I need to make the content fullscreen.

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).apply {
    hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
    systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
}
```

This is supposed to hide both the status and navigation bars, but only the former gets hidden.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post, it helped me get to the bottom of a similar issue.

To answer your question, there's a separate flag for navigation bars, you need to add this snippet as well:

```
hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())
```